# How to force deletion of a python object?

Tags: python, constructor, garbage-collection, destructor, reference-counting

I am curious about the details of `__del__` in python, when and why it should be used and what it shouldn't be used for.  I've learned the hard way that it is not really like what one would naively expected from a destructor, in that it is not the opposite of `__new__` / `__init__`.

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = None

    def open(self):
        if self.bar != 'open':
            print 'opening the bar'
            self.bar = 'open'

    def close(self):
        if self.bar != 'closed':
            print 'closing the bar'
            self.bar = 'close'

    def __del__(self):
        self.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = Foo()
    foo.open()
    del foo
    import gc
    gc.collect()
```

I saw in the documentation that it is *not* guaranteed `__del__()` methods are called for objects that still exist when the interpreter exits.

1. how can it be guaranteed that for any `Foo` instances existing when the interpreter exits, the bar is closed?
2. in the code snippet above does the bar get closed on `del foo` or on `gc.collect()`... or neither?  if you want finer control of those details (e.g. the bar should be closed when the object is unreferenced) what is the usual way to implement that?
3. when `__del__` is called is it guaranteed that `__init__` has already been called?  what about if the `__init__` raised?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The way to close resources are context managers, aka the `with` statement:

```
class Foo(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self.bar = None

  def __enter__(self):
    if self.bar != 'open':
      print 'opening the bar'
      self.bar = 'open'
    return self # this is bound to the `as` part

  def close(self):
    if self.bar != 'closed':
      print 'closing the bar'
      self.bar = 'close'

  def __exit__(self, *err):
    self.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  with Foo() as foo:
    print foo, foo.bar
```

output:

```
opening the bar
<__main__.Foo object at 0x17079d0> open
closing the bar
```

---

2) Python's objects get deleted when their reference count is 0. In your example the `del foo` removes the last reference so `__del__` is called instantly. The GC has no part in this.

```
class Foo(object):

    def __del__(self):
        print "deling", self

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import gc
    gc.disable() # no gc
    f = Foo()
    print "before"
    del f # f gets deleted right away
    print "after"
```

output:

```
before
deling <__main__.Foo object at 0xc49690>
after
```

The `gc` has nothing to do with deleting your and most other objects. It's there to clean up when simple reference counting does not work, because of self-references or circular references:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, other=None):
        # make a circular reference
        self.link = other
        if other is not None:
            other.link = self

    def __del__(self):
        print "deling", self

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import gc
    gc.disable()   
    f = Foo(Foo())
    print "before"
    del f # nothing gets deleted here
    print "after"
    gc.collect()
    print gc.garbage # The GC knows the two Foos are garbage, but won't delete
                     # them because they have a __del__ method
    print "after gc"
    # break up the cycle and delete the reference from gc.garbage
    del gc.garbage[0].link, gc.garbage[:]
    print "done"
```

output:

```
before
after
[<__main__.Foo object at 0x22ed8d0>, <__main__.Foo object at 0x22ed950>]
after gc
deling <__main__.Foo object at 0x22ed950>
deling <__main__.Foo object at 0x22ed8d0>
done
```

---

3) Lets see:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):

        raise Exception

    def __del__(self):
        print "deling", self

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = Foo()
```

gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asd.py", line 10, in <module>
    f = Foo()
  File "asd.py", line 4, in __init__
    raise Exception
Exception
deling <__main__.Foo object at 0xa3a910>
```

Objects are created with `__new__` then passed to `__init__` as `self`. After a exception in `__init__`, the object will typically not have a name (ie the `f =` part isn't run) so their ref count is 0. This means that the object is deleted normally and `__del__` is called.

Comment: > The way to close resources are context managers, aka the with statement.
Excellent tip. Didn't know `with` could be used for containing scope for any object this way.

Answer (score 8):

In general, to make sure something happens no matter what, you use

```
from exceptions import NameError

try:
    f = open(x)
except ErrorType as e:
    pass # handle the error
finally:
    try:
        f.close()
    except NameError: pass
```

`finally` blocks will be run whether or not there is an error in the `try` block, and whether or not there is an error in any error handling that takes place in `except` blocks. If you don't handle an exception that is raised, it will still be raised after the `finally` block is excecuted.

The general way to make sure a file is closed is to use a "context manager".

http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers

```
with open(x) as f:
    # do stuff
```

This will automatically close `f`.

For your question #2, `bar` gets closed on immediately when it's reference count reaches zero, so on `del foo` if there are no other references.

Objects are NOT created by `__init__`, they're created by `__new__`.

[http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.**new**](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__)

When you do `foo = Foo()` two things are actually happening, first a new object is being created, `__new__`, then it is being initialized, `__init__`. So there is no way you could possibly call `del foo` before both those steps have taken place. However, if there is an error in `__init__`, `__del__` will still be called because the object was actually already created in `__new__`.

Edit: Corrected when deletion happens if a reference count decreases to zero.

Comment: Your `try..except..finally` example is broken: if `open()` throws an exception `f` will be unset and the finally won't work.

Comment: Thanks, fixed. However, it would still ensure that `f` was closed, as the error only occured in the case it was never opened.

Comment: @afg you are wrong about the gc and when objects are deleted, see my answer.

Comment: @Jochen-Ritzel Got you. your examples are very illustrative.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you are looking for a [context manager](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)?

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.bar = None
...   def __enter__(self):
...     if self.bar != 'open':
...       print 'opening the bar'
...       self.bar = 'open'
...   def __exit__(self, type_, value, traceback):
...     if self.bar != 'closed':
...       print 'closing the bar', type_, value, traceback
...       self.bar = 'close'
... 
>>> 
>>> with Foo() as f:
...     # oh no something crashes the program
...     sys.exit(0)
... 
opening the bar
closing the bar <type 'exceptions.SystemExit'> 0 <traceback object at 0xb7720cfc>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Add an [exit handler](http://docs.python.org/library/atexit.html) that closes all the bars.
2. `__del__()` gets called when the number of references to an object hits 0 while the VM is still running. This may be caused by the GC.
3. If `__init__()` raises an exception then the object is assumed to be incomplete and `__del__()` won't be invoked.

Comment: As a side note: os._exit allows complete bypass of all close handling functions.