# how to achieve - file write open on __del__?

Tags: python, memory, garbage-collection, destructor, del

I m trying to do a some activity on class obj destruction.
How do I achieve file open in `__del__` function?
(I m using Python 3.4)

```
class iam(object):

    def __init__(self):
        print("I m born")

    def __del__(self):
        f = open("memory_report.txt", "w")
        f.write("He gone safe")
        f.close()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    i = iam()
    print("Script Ends. Now to GC clean memory")


Output:
```

---

```
I m born
Script Ends. Now to GC clean memory
Exception ignored in: <bound method iam.__del__ of <__main__.iam object at 0x00000000022F1A58>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Kumaresan\Code\Python\CommonLib\src\kmxPyQt\devConsole3\tet.py", line 14, in __del__
NameError: name 'open' is not defined
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  Using `__del__` at all is risky.  Using it to do something like open a file is a sure road to trouble.

Comment: @Jamie Bull: It might work for you but you can't rely on `__del__` being called.

Comment: You can't rely on other resources being available when `__del__` is called if I'm reading [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) correctly. As in OP's case where `__del__` is being called but can't find `open`.

Comment: I m using Python 3.4

Comment: related:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/6772481/674039

Answer (score 4):

Below code is work fine.

```
class iam(object):

def __init__(self):
    print("I m born")

def __del__(self):
    #"open" function still in __builtins__ 
    f = open("memory_report.txt", "w")
    f.write("He gone safe")
    f.close()

def write_iam():
        i=iam()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    write_iam()
    print("Script Ends. Now to GC clean memory")
```

In this case:

```
class iam(object):

def __init__(self):
    print("I m born")

def __del__(self):
    #__builtins__.open  has remove 
    f = open("memory_report.txt", "w")
    f.write("He gone safe")
    f.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    i = iam()
    print("Script Ends. Now to GC clean memory")
```

When  exit the __main__ function, before GC  delete the "i" instance (execute i.__delete__)   "open" function has remove from __builtins__.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is, as MuSheng tried [to explain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26545347/11498), that the `__builtins__` are removed before *your* `__del__` is called.

You can trigger the `__del__` yourself by assigning None to the variable.

MuSheng's code could be this:

```
class iam():
    def __init__(self):
        print("I m born")

    def __del__(self):
        #"open" function still in __builtins__ 
        with open("memory_report.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write("He gone safe")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    i = iam()
    i = None # This triggers `__del__`
    print("Script Ends. Now to GC clean memory")
```

MuSheng deserves some upvotes, IMO

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, *don't* use the ____del___ method to perform such cleanup. Instead, use either contextmanagers (**with**-statement) or register atexit-handlers.

Comment: atexit handlers helped me

Answer (score 2):

Below is an alternate I used - Using atexit handlers:

```
import atexit


class iam(object):

    def __init__(self):
        print("I m born")
        atexit.register(self.cleanup)

    def cleanup(self):
        f = open("memory_report.txt", "w")
        f.write("He gone safe")
        f.close()
        print ("Done")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    i = iam()
    print("Script Ends. Now to GC clean memory")
```

### Output:

```
I m born
Script Ends. Now to GC clean memory
Done
```