# How to make an object indestructible even with force deletion?

Tags: python, class, object, del

How can I make an object such **indestructible** that even with using `del` reserved word (*I think it means force deletion*) it won't be deleted?

I'm storing the objects in a list, like this:

```
list = [obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4 ....]
del list[0]
```

I think I have to do some tricks with `__del__()` within the class of object but how?

Comment: Objects are deleted only when there are no names that refer to them.  In that case, your object can't be used, so why do you want it to be around?

Comment: `del` doesn't mean "force deletion".

Comment: I'm afraid of accidentally delete some object from a list? What is wrong with question?

Comment: @BrenBarn So what is force deletion that mentioned in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772481/how-to-force-deletion-of-a-python-object

Comment: `del` deletes a *name*, not an object.  The object is deleted only if all names that point to it are removed.

Comment: @mertyildiran: That question indicates a misunderstanding of `del` and object deletion.  The *answers* to the question show better ways of achieving what that question was trying to do with `del`.  What are *you* trying to do with `del`?  Basically, when an object gets deleted in Python is not under your control.  There is no such thing as "force deletion" in Python.

Comment: If your question has anything to do with deleting items in a list I think that should be explained in the question.

Comment: @zondo I'm sorry, I didn't say `del` is an object. But I have a lack of knowledge about `del` that is obvious.

Comment: What I mean is this: `x = [0]` `y = x` `del x`  The list still exists.  `del` just means that the *name* `x` no longer exists.  The list itself exists until all names for it are removed.

Comment: @zondo Only by garbage collector right? What do you mean with names?

Comment: So you mean `del` is removing pointer in C? Allocated memory block will be protected even the name doesn't exist anymore. So it's not completely deleting it.

Comment: @mertyildiran This is not C, you do not allocate memory blocks, instead you create objects and give names to them.

Comment: @Goyo So what's the condition for deletion of an object? Could you give me an example? "until all names for it are removed" what is the meaning of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects in python have reference count which basically means the amount of places an object exist in. Using `del` removes one reference to the object (it does not force delete it). [`__del__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) is then called when 0 references are left. You may create a new reference to the object and this way prevent it's deletion like so:

```
class obj:
    def __del__(self):
         global _ref
         _ref = self
         return
```

This will prevent the deletion of the object by creating a global reference.
Keep in mind it is not suggested to do so as it will prevent the garbage collector from working correctly.

**UPDATE:**

In case you are using a list, you should convert it to an immutable object such as a `tuple` in order to prevent changes like deletion as so:

```
mylist = [obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4 ....]
mylist = tuple(mylist)
```

Comment: I've just realized that I need to use an immutable object like **tuple** to store names that are referencing to my "protected" object. Please add this to your answer and I will make it correct answer.

Comment: @mertyildiran Added, but keep in mind converting to tuple will not allow any modification to the tuple itself (It will however allow modification to the inner objects)