# How to call destructor of C++ class safely from a Python wrapper class using ctypes?

Tags: python, c++, wrapper, destructor

I built a C++ shared library, that exports functions for constructing, destructing and interacting with an implemented class. I want to write a wrapper class in Python, which loads the compiled .dll and wraps all the functions as a class using `ctypes` .

How do I wrap the destructor function of the C++ class safely so it will be called in any case (Normal Garbage Collection, Exceptions etc) ?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be calling the destructor at all. If you are using `new` to create the object, you should call `delete` on it to destroy the object, not call the destructor. How this call can be wrapped in a function that python's ctypes will call at an appropriate time, I don't know.

Comment: Yes you are right. What I meant is: I have an exported function that deletes the pointer/object passed as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Python's [data model doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html):

> Objects are never explicitly destroyed; however, when they become unreachable they may be garbage-collected. An implementation is allowed to postpone garbage collection or omit it altogether...
>
> ...
>
> Some objects contain references to “external” resources such as open files or windows. It is understood that these resources are freed when the object is garbage-collected, but since garbage collection is not guaranteed to happen, such objects also provide an explicit way to release the external resource, usually a close() method. Programs are strongly recommended to explicitly close such objects. The `try…finally` statement and the `with` statement provide convenient ways to do this.

So even if in most cases `__del__` method of an object is being called by GC, it is not guaranteed. `with` statement (from [PEP 343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)) on the other hand guarantees that if `__enter__` method of the object succeeded, then `__exit__` method will be called at the end of the statement, both in case of normal execution and in case of exception. (More detailed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40536821/python-enter-exit-vs-init-or-new-del))

An example could be as below, with the usage of "object-closing" context manager from PEP 343 examples, and a wrapper class with `close` method which calls native object's destructor:

```
class NativeObjectWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.nativeObject = nativeLib.CreateInstance()
    def close(self):
        nativeLib.DestructorFunction(self.nativeObject)
        
class closing(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
    def __enter__(self):
        return self.obj
    def __exit__(self, *exc_info):
        try:
            close_it = self.obj.close
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        else:
            close_it()
            
#example of usage
with closing(NativeObjectWrapper()) as objectWrapper:
    ... #some usage of native wrapper
```